# Regex to capture Maven test output

Tags: regex, maven, testing, continuous-integration, reporting

I have this Maven output when I run my tests:

```
...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 77, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  42:09 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-25T10:40:21Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project ***-***-******-*****: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
...
```

I want to capture this line with Regex or otherwise:

```
Tests run: 77, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0
```

I don't need to capture it exactly, but at least the general area, as each test class produces its own test summary of tests run, passed etc.

The RegEx I have come up with so far is:

```
((?<=\[ERROR\]).*\n).*((?=BUILD).*\n)
```

Which doesn't work for some reason.

How can I do this?

Comment: It seems that currently you are not matching the newlines. You might use a pattern like `(?<=\[ERROR\])(.*\n)[\s\S]*?(?=\bBUILD\b)` https://regex101.com/r/yqc1WS/1 or `\[ERROR\](.*)(?:\n(?!.* BUILD\b).*)*\n.* BUILD\b` https://regex101.com/r/AC4R38/1

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However, i've discovered an issue. Since there are multiple `[ERROR]`'s up until that final error log. It captures an earlier `[ERROR]` and not the one immediately preceding the final log. Is there a way to capture the last occurrence in which this capture group is valid?

Comment: Yes in that case you can also rule out matching `[ERROR]` in between after matching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
\[ERROR](.*)(?:\n(?!.* BUILD\b|\[ERROR]).*)*\n.* BUILD\b
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `\[ERROR\]` Match `[ERROR]`
- `(.*)` Capture group 1, match the whole line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!` A negative lookahead to assert what is to the right is not

    - `.* BUILD\b` Match  `BUILD` in the line
    - `|` Or
    - `\[ERROR]` Match `[ERROR]`
  - `)` Close the lookahead
  - `.*` Match the whole line
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat
- `\n.* BUILD\b` Match a newline and the line with  `BUILD`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g9F1xS/1)